# Why do I only recive one Object in this foreach-statement?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, foreach

I get kind of mad with this piece of code:

```
Entity.GuidArrayArray.gaa[0]) is a static Guid[][]
Entity.Customer is an non static ClassObject with several propperties e.G .id which is a Guid
Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource is a static BindingList<Entity.Customer>
Entity.CustomerCollection.customerCollection is a static List<Entity.Customer>
```

gaa[0] contains 6 different Guids which are equal to the .id of the same ammount of Customer in customerCollection. Before this Code starts CustomerSource contains Clones of customerCollection.

The outcome i wish to get (in this special case) is (same as before) a Clone of Each Object in customerCollection added into CustomerSource. What I get instead is only the last Object in the list. I guess it has something to do with the foreach-statement, that each guid in gaa[0] selects its connected Object and overwrites the previos, but i see no way to prevent this. I hope you have any idea?

```
    public static void GuidInput()
    {
        CustomerFiller(Entity.GuidArrayArray.gaa[0]);
    }

    private static void CustomerFiller(Guid[] guidArray)
    {
        foreach (Guid g in guidArray)
            Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource = ToBindingList(Entity.CustomerCollection.customerCollection.Where(a => a.id == g).ToList());
    }

    private static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(List<T> input)
    {

        BindingList<T> output = new BindingList<T>(Clone(input));
        return output;
    }
    private static List<T> Clone<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        List<T> clonedList = new List<T>(input);
        return clonedList;
    }
```

EDIT:

---

Solution:

```
private static void CustomerFiller(Guid[] guidArray)
    {
        foreach (Guid g in guidArray)
        {
            List<Entity.Customer> abc =new List<Entity.Customer>();
            foreach (Guid g in guidArray)
                abc.AddRange(Entity.CustomerCollection.customerCollection.Where(a => a.id == g));
            Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource = ToBindingList(abc);
            Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource = Reduce(Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource, x => x.id);
        }
```

But I still hope to get rid of the foreach.

Comment: Is it not because you're setting `CustomerSource` equal to the list of customer collection items each iteration, thus will be equal to the binding list of `customerCollection` items for the last guid in `guidArray` when the loop finished?

Comment: @JoshuaBrodie Thanks, you were correct. I edited my entry to show the solution. Still I might like to get rid of the foreach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static void CustomerFiller(Guid[] guidArray)
{       
  Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource = ToBindingList(Entity.CustomerCollection.customerCollection.Where(a => guidArray.Contains(a.id) ).ToList());
}
```